# Typo3 extension - just save file path

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.1.x, typo3-4.5, typo3-6.2.x

I created an extension via kickstarter in Typo3 4.5.

There is a field in the backend where the user should upload / choose a file from fileadmin. I created this field in kickstarter with the type File.

The problem is that I don't want Typo3 to copy the file in uploads/extensionname because there will be uploaded big files. I just want to save the path to the file which will be located somewhere in fileadmin.

Is there any possibilty to do this? (It should also run in 6.1 and 6.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use type [file_reference](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Reference/Columns/Group/Index.html#internal-type) instead of `file`. I don't know how well that works in 6.x, but probably you don't need any adaptions.